# Computing $DF_{|_f}$ of $F(f)(x)=\int^{x}_{0}\cos\big(f^2(t)\big)dt,\text{ } x\in [0,1].$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, banach-spaces

Let $X=\mathcal{C}([0,1])$ be the Banach space of continuous functions on $[0,1]$ (with the supremum norm) and define a map $F:X\rightarrow X$ by 
$$ F(f)(x)=\int^{x}_{0}\cos\big(f^2(t)\big)dt,\text{ } x\in [0,1]. $$
Show that $F$ is Fréchet differentiable and compute the Fréchet derivative $DF_{|_f}$ for each $f\in X$.

---

To be Fréchet differentiable means the following: Let $X,Y$ be normed vector spaces, U open in X, and $F:U\rightarrow Y$. Let $x,h\in U$ and let $T:X\rightarrow Y$ be a linear map. Then the limit
$$ \underset{h\rightarrow 0}{\lim}\frac{||F(x+h)-F(x)-Th||_Y}{||h||_X}=0$$
exists. We denote $T$ as $DF_{|_x}$.

---

Making use of $cos(A+\epsilon B)-cosA=-\epsilon BsinA + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2)$. we get that
\begin{equation} 
cos\big[(f(x)+h(x))^2\big]=cos(f^2(x))-h(x)[2f(x)+h(x)]sin(f^2(x)) + \mathcal{O}(h^2(x)). 
\end{equation}
Therefore, we have that
\begin{align*}F(f+h)(x)-F(f)(x)
&=\int^{x}_{0}-h(x)[2f(x)+h(x)]sin(f^2(x))+\mathcal{O}(h^2(x))dx \\
&=\int^{x}_{0}-2f(x)h(x)sin(f^2(x))-h^2(x)sin(f^2(x))+\mathcal{O}(h^2(x))dx \\
&=\int^{x}_{0}-2f(x)h(x)sin(f^2(x))+\mathcal{O}(h^2(x))dx \\
\end{align*}
The last line follows since $-h^2(x)sin(f^2(x))$ is a Big-$\mathcal{O}$ of $h^2(x)$.

Now put $DF_{|_f}(h)=\int^{x}_{0}-2f(x)h(x)sin(f^2(x))dx$ as this expression is linear in $h(x).$

Hence, we have that
$$ F(f+h)(x)-F(f)(x)-DF_{|_f}(h)=\int^{x}_{0}\mathcal{O}(h^2(x))dx $$

And here I am now stuck. I don't know what to do with the Big-$\mathcal{O}$ notation in the integral. Am I doing this correctly?

Comment: Recall $\cos(A+\varepsilon B)-\cos A=-\varepsilon B\sin A+O(\varepsilon^2)$

Comment: I updated my post. Can you tell me if the steps so far are correct?